# Find a specific object in array with Mongoose and Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to return a specific object in an array with mongoose. My document is as follows:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "577a9345ba1e2a1100624be7"
},
"name": "John Doe",
"password": "$2a$10$NzqAqxTRy8XLCHG8h3Q7IOLBSFCfBJ7R5JqHy1XHHYN.1h074bWJK",
"__v": 0,
"birthDate": "14.07.2016",
"academic": [
    {
        "about": "asdfasdf",
        "to": "asdf",
        "from": "asfdasdf",
        "institute": "asdfasdf",
        "qualification": "asdfasdf",
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "579111b3e68d489f1ff8b6dc"
        }
    }
]
```

}

I want to return that academic object in the list. I am passing in the institute name into the route my code is as follows:

```
    getAcademicInstituteByName: function(req, name, cb){
    User.findById(req.user.id, function (err, user) {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(user){
            academic = user.academic.institute(name);
            return cb(null, academic);
        }
    });
```

But this is not working since I am getting an error saying user.academic.institute is not a function. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: are you trying to get the value of institute? "asdfasdf"?

Comment: Hi there, I am trying to return that entire object in that array by passing in the value of the institute "asdfasdf"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user.academic.institute` is an array, so you can use regular array operations to find the entry you're interested in:

```
var academic = user.academic.institute.filter(i => i.institute === name)
                                      .pop();
return cb(null, academic);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 academic = user.academic.institute;
```

this should work, though I haven't tested it.